# Force Closing App

Tags: android

Im not sure why, but my app all of a sudden keeps force closing on me. It was working fine earlier.

Please have a look.

```
public class AgentPortalActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

String username;
String password;
Button login;
EditText uid;
EditText pwd;
CheckBox chkRememberPassword;
SharedPreferences loginPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor loginPrefsEditor;
Boolean saveLogin;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // User Id and Password Text Fields
    uid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uid);
    pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pw);

    // Converts the Text in the User Id and Password field to Strings
    username = uid.getText().toString();
    password = pwd.getText().toString();

    // Login Button On Click Listener
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    login.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Remember Password Save Properties
    chkRememberPassword = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkRememberPassword);
    loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    loginPrefsEditor = loginPreferences.edit();

    saveLogin = loginPreferences.getBoolean("saveLogin", false);

    if (saveLogin == true) {
        uid.setText(loginPreferences.getString(username, ""));
        pwd.setText(loginPreferences.getString(password, ""));
        chkRememberPassword.setChecked(true);
        // End

    }
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == login) {

        // Loading Dialog Box
        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
                AgentPortalActivity.this);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setMessage("Logging In...");
        dialog.show();

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (dialog.getProgress() < dialog.getMax()) {

                    try {

                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    } catch (Exception e) {/* no-op */
                    }
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        t.start();
        // End Of Loading Dialog Box

        // Hides Soft Keyboard
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(uid.getWindowToken(), 0);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(pwd.getWindowToken(), 0);

        // Button OnClick Vibrating Service
        Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vib.vibrate(50);

        // Send username and password strings into screen1 class
        Intent i = new Intent(this, screen1.class);
        i.putExtra("uid", username);
        i.putExtra("pwd", password);
        startActivity(i);
        // End

        if (chkRememberPassword.isChecked()) {
            loginPrefsEditor.putBoolean("saveLogin", true);
            loginPrefsEditor.putString(username, username);
            loginPrefsEditor.putString(password, password);
            loginPrefsEditor.commit();
        } else {
            loginPrefsEditor.clear();
            loginPrefsEditor.commit();
        }

        doSomethingElse();
    }
}

public void doSomethingElse() {

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);

}
```

}

Heres my second class

```
public class screen1 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

String username;
String password;

// EditTexts
final EditText milein = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.milein);
final EditText zipin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zipin);
final EditText mileout = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mileout);
final EditText zipout = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zipout);
final EditText feed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.feed);

// TextViews
final TextView dispatch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispatch);
final TextView dispatchnum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispatchnum);
final TextView csr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.csr);
final TextView csrnum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.csrnum);
final TextView it = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.it);
final TextView itnum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itnum);
final TextView thoughts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thoughts);
final TextView information = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.information);

//ToggleButtons
final ToggleButton checkinbutton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.checkinbutton);

// Buttons
final Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
final Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen1);

    // Calls String from AgentPortalActivity class to pass through to
    // screen1 class
    Intent i = getIntent();
    username = i.getExtras().getString("uid");
    password = i.getExtras().getString("pwd");
    // End

    // Passes username and password strings and inserts into URL for login
    // and pwd
    JSONObject json = JSONfunction
            .getJSONfromURL("http://whatever.com/api/?type=json&uid="
                    + (username) + "&pwd=" + (password));
    // End

    try {

        // boolean suspended = json.getBoolean("suspended");
        String firstName = json.getString("firstName");
        String lastName = json.getString("lastName");
        // int checkdin = json.getInt("checkedin");
        // int checkindatetime = json.getInt("checkindatetime");

        // Get Json object address
        JSONObject address = json.getJSONObject("address");
        String streetAddress = address.getString("streetAddress");
        String city = address.getString("city");
        String state = address.getString("state");
        String postalCode = address.getString("postalCode");
        // End

        // Get PhoneNumber Array
        JSONArray phoneNumbers = json.getJSONArray("phoneNumber");
        // String type = phoneNumbers.getJSONObject(0).getString("type");
        String number = phoneNumbers.getJSONObject(0).getString("number");
        // End

        information.setText("Hello," + " " + (firstName) + " " + (lastName)
                + "!" + " " + "Your Home Number is" + " " + (number) + " "
                + "Your Address is" + " " + (streetAddress) + " " + (city)
                + " " + (state) + " " + (postalCode));

    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    /** Submit Button Invisible Child Properties */
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Button OnClick Vibrating Service
            Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vib.vibrate(50);

            // Submit Mile-IN Mile-Out Button
            if (submit.isPressed()) {
                milein.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                zipin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mileout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                zipout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                submit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                dispatch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                dispatchnum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                csr.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                csrnum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                it.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                itnum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                thoughts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                feed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                send.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // End

                // Button OnClick Vibrating Service
                Vibrator vib1 = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vib1.vibrate(50);
                // End

                // Toast "Please Wait" Upon Clicking Submit Button
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please Wait...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // End

            }
        }
    });

    // Boolean for Check-In Button Sharedpreferences
    final SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean tgpref = preferences.getBoolean("tgpref", false);
    checkinbutton.setChecked(tgpref);
    // End

    // ToggleButton Check-IN
    checkinbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Button OnClick Vibrating Service
            Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vib.vibrate(50);
            // End

            // Only Displays Mile-in Zip-in and Submit Button
            if (checkinbutton.isChecked()) {
                milein.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                zipin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                submit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mileout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                zipout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                dispatch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                dispatchnum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                csr.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                csrnum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                it.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                itnum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                thoughts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                feed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                send.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // End

                // Button OnClick Vibrating Service
                Vibrator vib1 = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vib1.vibrate(50);
                // End

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Checking In...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // Boolean Preferences for Checkinbutton ToggleButton
                // Remembers Toggle State Checked
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                final SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                boolean tgpref = preferences.getBoolean("tgpref", false);
                checkinbutton.setChecked(tgpref);
                editor.putBoolean("tgpref", true);
                editor.commit();
                // End

            } else {

                mileout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                zipout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                submit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                milein.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                zipin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                dispatch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                dispatchnum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                csr.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                csrnum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                it.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                itnum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                thoughts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                feed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                send.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                // Boolean Preferences for Checkinbutton ToggleButton
                // Remembers Toggle State Un-Checked
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("tgpref", false);
                editor.commit();
                // End

                // AlertDialog Meal-Periods Button Configurations
                final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        screen1.this).create();
                alertDialog
                        .setMessage("I hereby verify that I have received all my 10 minute rest periods and 30 minute meal breaks today.");
                alertDialog.setButton("Agree",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                        "Checking Out...",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.setButton2("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        getBaseContext(),
                                        "Please contact Ro*** Mu*** (Human Resource) to report any discrepancies",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                checkinbutton.setChecked(true);
                                milein.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                zipin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                mileout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                zipout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                submit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                dispatch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                dispatchnum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                csr.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                csrnum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                it.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                itnum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                thoughts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                feed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                send.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences
                                        .edit();
                                editor.putBoolean("tgpref", true);
                                editor.commit();
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();
                // End

            }
        };
    });

    Button statusbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.statusbutton);
    statusbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Button OnClick Vibrating Service
            Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vib.vibrate(50);
            // End

            /** Fading Transition Effect */
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);

            /** Status Bar */
            final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(screen1.this);
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            dialog.setMessage("Getting Status Please Wait...");
            dialog.show();

            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    while (dialog.getProgress() < dialog.getMax()) {
                        try {

                            // Send username and password strings into
                            // screen1 class
                            Intent i = new Intent(screen1.this,
                                    statuspage.class);
                            i.putExtra("uid", username);
                            i.putExtra("pwd", password);
                            startActivity(i);
                            // End

                            Thread.sleep(50);
                        } catch (Exception e) {/* no-op */
                        }
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            t.start();
            /** End Of Status Bar */

        }

    });

    Button jobs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.jobs);
    jobs.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Button OnClick Vibrating Service
            Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vib.vibrate(50);

            startActivity(new Intent(screen1.this, Jobs.class));
            screen1.this.finish();

            /** Fading Transition Effect */
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);

            /** Status Bar */
            final ProgressDialog dialog2 = new ProgressDialog(screen1.this);
            dialog2.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            dialog2.setMessage("Loading Jobs Please Wait...");
            dialog2.show();

            Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    while (dialog2.getProgress() < dialog2.getMax()) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(50);
                        } catch (Exception e) {/* no-op */
                        }
                    }
                    dialog2.dismiss();
                }
            });
            t1.start();
            /** End Of Status Bar */
        }

    });

    Button contact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contact);
    contact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Button OnClick Vibrating Service
            Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vib.vibrate(50);

            dispatch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            dispatchnum.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            csr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            csrnum.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            it.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            itnum.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            milein.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            zipin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mileout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            zipout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            submit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            thoughts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            feed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            send.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });

    Button feedback = (Button) findViewById(R.id.feedback);
    feedback.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Button OnClick Vibrating Service
            Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vib.vibrate(50);

            thoughts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            feed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            send.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            milein.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            zipin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mileout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            zipout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            submit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            dispatch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            dispatchnum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            csr.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            csrnum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            it.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            itnum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    // Button OnClick Vibrating Service
    Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vib.vibrate(50);

    startActivity(new Intent(screen1.this, AgentPortalActivity.class));
    screen1.this.finish();

    /** Fading Transition Effect */
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    return;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
```

}

And Here is my LogCat

```
03-22 09:44:56.031: I/Process(21770): Sending signal. PID: 21770 SIG: 9
03-22 09:44:57.679: D/dalvikvm(21798): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 58K, 44% free 3036K/5379K, external 1596K/2108K, paused 35ms
03-22 09:44:57.788: D/dalvikvm(21798): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 11K, 44% free 3056K/5379K, external 3498K/3748K, paused 36ms
03-22 09:44:57.804: D/AndroidRuntime(21798): Shutting down VM
03-22 09:44:57.804: W/dalvikvm(21798): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
03-22 09:44:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(21798): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 09:44:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(21798): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jetdelivery.mobile/com.jetdelivery.mobile.AgentPortalActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 09:44:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(21798):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
03-22 09:44:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(21798):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
03-22 09:44:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(21798):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-22 09:44:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(21798):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
03-22 09:44:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(21798):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 09:44:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(21798):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-22 09:44:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(21798):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-22 09:44:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(21798):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 09:44:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(21798):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-22 09:44:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(21798):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
03-22 09:44:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(21798):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-22 09:44:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(21798):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-22 09:44:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(21798): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 09:44:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(21798):    at com.jetdelivery.mobile.AgentPortalActivity.onCreate(AgentPortalActivity.java:40)
03-22 09:44:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(21798):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-22 09:44:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(21798):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
03-22 09:44:57.812: E/AndroidRuntime(21798):    ... 11 more
03-22 09:45:04.652: I/Process(21798): Sending signal. PID: 21798 SIG: 9
```

Comment: There's some object that you're using that has a value of null (hence your NullPointerException). What's on line 40 of AgentPortalActivity.java?

Comment: Just run in debug mode, step through your onCreate and see what is thrown Null Pointer Exception...

Comment: sorry, not quite sure what you mean @ line 40

Comment: Can anyone else help me debug the second class? (screen1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Converts the Text in the User Id and Password field to Strings
    username = uid.getText().toString();
    password = pwd.getText().toString();
```

`These lines` are giving you the `NullPointerExcepton`. Because you are trying to get the text in OnCreate() itself from these edittexts when they don't contain anything .The user is not able to see and interact with the views until onResume() . You would need to push these two lines and all other code off onCreate and on some event firing such as a button click.
Try this code. I have moved them to onClick() to give you an idea:

```
public class AgentPortalActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

String username;
String password;
Button login;
EditText uid;
EditText pwd;
CheckBox chkRememberPassword;
SharedPreferences loginPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor loginPrefsEditor;
Boolean saveLogin;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // User Id and Password Text Fields
    uid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uid);
    pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pw);



    // Login Button On Click Listener
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    login.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Remember Password Save Properties
    chkRememberPassword = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkRememberPassword);
    loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    loginPrefsEditor = loginPreferences.edit();

    saveLogin = loginPreferences.getBoolean("saveLogin", false);

    if (saveLogin == true) {
        uid.setText(loginPreferences.getString(username, ""));
        pwd.setText(loginPreferences.getString(password, ""));
        chkRememberPassword.setChecked(true);
        // End

    }
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == login) {


         // Converts the Text in the User Id and Password field to Strings
        username = uid.getText().toString();
        password = pwd.getText().toString();

        // Loading Dialog Box
        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
                AgentPortalActivity.this);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setMessage("Logging In...");
        dialog.show();

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (dialog.getProgress() < dialog.getMax()) {

                    try {

                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    } catch (Exception e) {/* no-op */
                    }
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        t.start();
        // End Of Loading Dialog Box

        // Hides Soft Keyboard
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(uid.getWindowToken(), 0);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(pwd.getWindowToken(), 0);

        // Button OnClick Vibrating Service
        Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vib.vibrate(50);

        // Send username and password strings into screen1 class
        Intent i = new Intent(this, screen1.class);
        i.putExtra("uid", username);
        i.putExtra("pwd", password);
        startActivity(i);
        // End

        if (chkRememberPassword.isChecked()) {
            loginPrefsEditor.putBoolean("saveLogin", true);
            loginPrefsEditor.putString(username, username);
            loginPrefsEditor.putString(password, password);
            loginPrefsEditor.commit();
        } else {
            loginPrefsEditor.clear();
            loginPrefsEditor.commit();
        }

        doSomethingElse();
    }
}

public void doSomethingElse() {

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);

}
```

Comment: Thanks Akhill! I got the main class working again, now I need to see why my second class (screen1) is acting up now.

Comment: Akhill, could you also help me figure out why my second class keeps crashing as well? been trying to figure it out for the past hour and i am stumped.

Comment: On my Screen1 class, im still getting debug errors. Im sorry, I wish I knew how to understand the logcats, however I tried moving my codes around because I think the its the same problem as my main Activity (NullPointerException)